# Sitecore: select items by field: TreelistEx

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have Sitecore folder named MyItems with items of type MyItem. I need to query the items from .net code either with sitecore query or with xpath. MyItem has field MyField of type TreelistEx. I need to select all items where MyField contains 'thevalue' (guid of other item). How can i do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string query = string.Format("/sitecore/content/MyItems/*[contains(@MyField,'{0}')]", thevalue);
Item[] myItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query);
```

I just pulled this code from my site and adjusted the names for your query.  It is fairly inefficient if you have a lot of MyItems, so I wouldn't use this on a page where performance is key.  The same query should work for any list-type field.

Comment: I put guid there: /sitecore/content/MyItems/*[contains(@MyField,'{33A77F25-8327-46B4-96FE-6652B8E40BD1}')] and it returns nothing (the element with this guid exists). Which way do you consider more efficient: fast query or something else? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't use functions in fast query, you can use sql like syntax with wildcards.  Behold:

```
string query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/MyItems/*[@MyField='%{0}%']", thevalue);
```

True story.  Word.

Source: Page 9 of "[Using Sitecore Fast Query](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf)" which I believe is behind an "account wall(tm)"

> Functions are not supported. However the contains() function can be
>   replaced by a string equality operator that contains  SQL wildcards. 
>   For example:  //*[contains(@Title, 'Sitecore')] is equivalent to 
>   fast://*[@Title = '%Sitecore%']"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use fast query as well

```
string query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/MyItems/*[contains(@MyField,'{0}')]", thevalue);
```

update: `sitecore` fast query doesn't support functions, so the `contains()` function will nor work in this query.