# how to access field values in a Item using sitecore Xpath Query

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a Rich Text Field inside an item template that includes Text.How to retrieve that field value using Xpath Query.

> /sitecore/content/Home/Data/Common Data/CommonDescription.

By using this Query I'm able to access Item.But my Question is how to access field inside that item using Xpath Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can get the field values and path is designed to retrieve items rather than field values.

Once you have the item you will then be able to get the fields using the api

```
Item[] items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(xpath);

foreach(Item item in items )
{
var richtextfield = item["field"]
...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Can we specify Field name of an Item in path

Comment: You always retrieve Items, but you can query fields to filter the set of items. Possibly not the best in terms of performance though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536201/sitecore-select-items-by-field-treelistex